# Re-broadcast wi-fi signal using USB dongle

Tags: wireless-networking, usb

I have a wireless connection on my campus that requires a username and password. The issue is my 3DS is unable to use this connection since it can only take a password when trying to connect. I have a Macbook Air, and I've read online about plugging via ethernet, and then redistribute the connection via wi-fi, but there's no ethernet ports to use in the dorm buildings.

Is there a way to plug one of these USB dongle devices into my laptop (which can connect) and re-broadcast its connection so my 3DS can connect? If so, what features would I require?

Comment: I want to make sure I understand: You would like to share your internet connection over WiFi. The connection you want to share is *also* using WiFi. You want to know if you can share this the same way you would normally share an interned connection, except you plan to use *2 separate* wireless network interfaces, rather than one wireless interface, and one wired. Did I get that right?

Comment: @Izam Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this link: http://www.mactip.net/share-internet-connection-mac/

*Slightly modified for your situation*

1. Connect to ethernet
2. In System preferences, look under Internet and Wireless for **Sharing**
3. In the list, click **Internet Sharing**
4. Select to share from **Wifi** to **Wifi**, or something similar. You might need to check to see which connection is linked to which adapter name.
5. Click **Wi-Fi Options** to configure the network. All of these options are up to you.
6. Finally, make sure the tick-box for **Internet Sharing** is **ticked**

You should be good!.

Comment: The problem is there's no wifi-to-wifi sharing

Comment: Not even with with more than one adapter attached? If so, this method is a bit complicated but would work if there is more than one computer available. You could share wifi-to-ethernet on one, connect the two Mac's via ethernet, and share ethernet-to-wifi on the other one, creating a really weird semi ad-hoc.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use two separate wireless interfaces (your built in airport card, and the USB dongle), you should be able to share your wireless connection the same way you would share your wired connection.

Just make sure that the wifi dongle you get is compatible with your Mac.

It *may* be possible that your universities network setup will interfere with network sharing in general (or at least require you to fiddle with some settings), but even if it does it shouldn't have anything to do with wired vs wireless.

Comment: OK thanks, I wasn't 100% sure. I've poked around and couldn't find an answer.